# Using ELMO with Keras?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, word-embedding

so first I was using GloVe in my model it worked fine, but now I want to switch to Elmo but I always get that error:

> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes
>   except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 20), (None,
>   20), (None, 20, 5)]

Can you please help me ?here's a snippet of my code: please let me know if you need more details.

## Elmo in Keras

```
class ElmoEmbeddingLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dimensions = 1024
        self.trainable = True
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
def build(self, input_shape):
        self.elmo = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable=self.trainable, name="{}_module".format(self.name))
        self.trainable_weights += K.tf.trainable_variables(scope="^{}_module/.*".format(self.name))
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).build(input_shape)
def call(self, x, mask=None):
        result = self.elmo(K.squeeze(K.cast(x, tf.string), axis=1),
                      as_dict=True,
                      signature='default',
                      )['default']
        return result
def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return K.not_equal(inputs, '--PAD--')
def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.dimensions)
```

## my Model

```
pos_embedding_layer = Embedding(output_dim = pos_tag_embedding_size,
                         input_dim = len(SPACY_POS_TAGS),
                         input_length = sent_maxlen,
                         name='pos_embedding_layer')
inputs = [Input((sent_maxlen,), dtype='int32', name='word_inputs'),
            Input((sent_maxlen,), dtype='int32', name='predicate_inputs'),
            Input((sent_maxlen,), dtype='int32', name='postags_inputs')]

# ElmoEmbeddingLayer()
embedding_layer = ElmoEmbeddingLayer()

embeddings = [embedding_layer(inputs[0]), 
               embedding_layer(inputs[1]),
                pos_embedding_layer(inputs[2])]

outputI = predict_layer(dropout(latent_layers(keras.layers.concatenate(embeddings))))
#error thrown here in outputI

## ------> 10]Build model 
model = Model(inputs, outputI)
```

Comment: You get the error *where exactly*? Please include the full error trace, and also fix the indentation in your `class` code.

Comment: the error is thrown In outputI (I indicated it in the code)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided your predict_layer.
But the Error is at the concatenate layer, so it's possible to solve this error using the code you've provided.
First of all, I'm surprised that you do not get your error earlier because Elmo with `signature='default'` requires a string as its input. (You should provide all your inputs as space-separated tokens e.g. 
`["the cat is on the mat", "dogs are in the fog"]`,
)
or use

```
embeddings = elmo(
inputs={
"tokens": tokens_input,
"sequence_len": tokens_length
},
signature="tokens",
as_dict=True)["elmo"]
```

But let's use space-separated tokens for now.

Thus, the only possible value for `ElmoEmbeddingLayer` input is `1` and we get

```
from keras.layers import Concatenate
sent_maxlen = 20
inputs = [Input(shape=(1, ), dtype="string"),
          Input(shape=(1, ), dtype="string"), 
          Input(shape=(sent_maxlen, ), dtype="int32")]
embeddings = [embedding_layer(inputs[0]), 
               embedding_layer(inputs[1]),
                pos_embedding_layer(inputs[2])]
concat = Concatenate(embeddings)
```

So for now it works (at least for me).
For the future I suggest that you change your signature from `'default'` to `'elmo'`.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes I figured that out that Elmos input should be words/sentence not 1 hot encoding. I think there are 2 main problems with Elmo and Keras 1] when I change the signature to 'Elmo' instead of default or LSTM as shown in https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2 it still outputs  2D vector never a 3D opposite to what's indicated in TF hub. 2] for some reason its untrainable as when model.summary() is printed the number of parameters shown in ELMo Embedding layer is 0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912745/in-keras-elmo-embedding-layer-has-0-parameters-is-this-normal

Comment: 2) do you have `sess = tf.Session();
K.set_session(sess)` in your code? as here https://github.com/strongio/keras-elmo/blob/master/Elmo%20Keras.ipynb .

Comment: Yes I came across Jacob's code (the GitHub link you provided), its the one im using now its the only trainable code available that solves issue number [2] , however issue 1 is still unresolved even using Jacobs code. Thanks